# 3D scatterplots in .net

Tags: .net, 3d, charts

I was wondering if there were any free libraries for .net for producing a 3D scatterplot, I haven't been able to find any using google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get some mileage out of this CodeProject article

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFChart3D.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this was basically exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I've found that [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org) is fairly straightforward to use. It can do other plot types in addition to scatterplots.